# Regex for finding an orphan less than sign in a string

Tags: regex

Ok so I tried coming with a good regex for this and I only go so far as the following:

```
(<(.*)(<))|(<(.*)).
```

But this has several issues.

Firstly I need my regex to point out the exact position of where the orphan less than is. The above regex will work perfectly for cases like `<10%` or `< abb123 <asdsad>`.

But it will also match `<asdad> <asdsad>` which I do not want to see matched. It will also match 
`<10% <asdad> <asdsad>` up to the less than sign of tag2 and I will get `<10% <asdad> <`.

I know this is happening because I am using `(.*)` but I am having trouble thinking of a way to come with a something that can match everything but > between the two < <, so cases like

```
  `<tag1><tag2>`
```

are not matched and I am able to match something like `<tag1><tag2><10%` in which a less than is not followed by any other less than or greater than but other letters, characters, and digits.

Comment: Than you Alex for fixing it.

Comment: Which fllavour are you using ?

Comment: This is just for my use in java code. Whatever the Pattern class uses to compile the regex.

Comment: can you add some sample of your input and highlight what you want to match and what you don't want.

Comment: ok so I will get a string like "<10% <Some Message here>". Usually what my code does is it deletes the less thans and greater thans and underlines "Some Message here" but it will also delete the < in <10% which I wouldn't like to see happen. So, I need to find the position of that less than.

Comment: so I need to match <10% < in this case. But in cases like <Some Message1> <Some Message 2>, it should not match anything. Also, it should match "<10%" in "<Message 1> <10%" string.

Comment: So basically you're looking for `<` characters that don't have a corresponding `>` after them?  http://regexr.com?373kl

Comment: ok ya that works actually. Thanks wiseguy.

Comment: can you please explain what is happening here. I am not so good with lookahead/lookbehind assertions.

Comment: also how could I make this work for greater than.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you're trying to find `<` characters that are not followed by corresponding `>` characters. Fitting your examples, we could do this:

```
<(?![^<]*>)
```

<sub>Ex: http://regexr.com/?373kl</sub>

Broken down, this is:

- a "less than" character `<`, followed by
- a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) `(?! )` which contains
- a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

```
<        # literal '<' character  
(?!      # negative lookahead
  [^<]*  # 0 or more characters that are not '<'
  >      # literal '>' character
)        # (closing the lookahead)
```

The lookahead sees if the next angle bracket it encounters is a `>`. Since it's a negative lookahead, it matches if that *isn't* the case.

---

*Update*

Doing the opposite -- identifying `>` characters that are not preceded by corresponding `<` characters -- is much trickier. This is because in most regex engines, including Java's, lookbehinds have to be of a fixed length (i.e., you can't use quantifiers like `+` and `*`). So we can't really use a lookbehind, which is conceptually what we need.

A few regex engines have a `\K` construct which allows us to effectively fake a variable-length lookbehind, but Java is not one of them. So we have to capture everything before the `>` we want, then find a way to ignore those characters.

Here's one way:

```
(?:^|>)[^<>\r\n]*(>)
```

<sub>Ex: http://regexr.com?373m2 (hover over matches to see groups)</sub>

There are parentheses around `>`, so it will be captured as a group on its own. (That way you can isolate it and gets its position in the string.)

Broken down, this is:

- a non-capturing group `(?:^|>)` (because we don't need it as a separate group),
- a negated character class `[^<>\r\n]*`, and
- a "greater than" `>` character in its own [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
(?:         # non-capturing group
  ^|>       # ^ start of line or '>' character 
)
[^<>\r\n]*  # 0 or more characters other than '<', '>', or newlines
(>)         # literal '>' character in its own capturing group
```

The idea here is that we start looking at the beginning of the line or after the last closing bracket `>` we passed. The next unmatched `>` we find will be alone in group #1.

Comment: thank you wiseguy. This helps a lot. But the regex for greater than didn't work for a case like this : 
>10% <underline1> <underline2> >20%. It matched the greater than of underline2. Still a good job!

Comment: Seems to work fine in the example I linked: http://regexr.com?373no  Is it working differently in Java?

Comment: I tried in rubular and it didn't work from greater than. This was my regex and test string:

(?:^|>)[^<>\r\n]*(>)
>10% <underline1> <underline2> >20%

Comment: @ProgrammerForNow Odd. I copied and pasted from your comment and it appeared to work as expected. http://rubular.com/r/2QHmyCn0ji Remember that the `>` itself is captured in _group #1_; ignore the whole pattern match, which also matches other characters we don't care about (such as in `> >`).

Comment: ok sure. So, that is what I was wondering about. I guess that pattern match can be ignored. Well this is good as it is. Thanks again.